# More resource usage friendly search than fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, performance, search, resources, full-text-search

I just use following code right now.

```
SELECT terms FROM searches WHERE MATCH(q) AGAINST('search term') LIMIT 20;
```

The table is MyISAM 90MB. terms has FULLTEXT INDEX and it is varchar(255). There are 1,000,000 rows on the table.

I wonder if there is any solution which is more resource usage friendly than fulltext search on MySQL? Especially in terms of memory.

By saying solution, I refer to any solution such as other types of databases, table structures etc.

and if the solution would be adaptable to a standart VPS or hosting in general, it would be extremely super duper perfect!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try SphinxSearch if you have a VPS

Comment: A debatable solution could be caching results, at least for the most common searches it will be effective.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). You can continue to use your MySQL database, have the Solr server index that column and use the Solr server to later do full-text searches on that column. There are even hosted solutions, see [WebSolr](http://websolr.com/).